# Java char addition (char1 = char2 + 10)

Tags: java

Why can't i do this?

```
public class test123 {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        char c = 34;
        char a = c + 10;

    }
}
```

new to java, so sorry if this question is actually stupid.

Comment: What is the result that you expect?

Comment: @Unmitigated even so, `char a = c + c;` wouldn't work.

Comment: The `+` operator is actually a function that accepts two arguments (one on the left side and the other on the right side). In this case, that function does not have a definition for `char operator+(char, int)`

Comment: You're experiencing [Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), i.e. your variable `c` is promoted to an `int` because `10` is an `int`-literal. And the result from an `int` addition is still an `int`, so you'd have to cast the result back to a `char`: `(char) (c + 10)`

Comment: `int` is the narrowest type for arithmetic. Narrower values are widened to `int`, and the result is `int`. Try `char a = (char)(c + 10);`

Comment: @Andy I cover that in my answer.

Comment: The best solution is to stop using the `char` type in Java. The `char` type is legacy, and is essentially broken. As a 16-bit value, it not capable of representing most Unicode characters. Instead, use Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers. Use `int` to hold your code point, add 10, verify the new number is valid ([`Character.isValidCodePoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isValidCodePoint(int))), then generate a single-character `String` holding that character: `Character.toString`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you add numbers, they undergo *binary numeric promotion*. That is, the operands are widened to allow them to be added.

When you add a `char` to an `int`, the `char` is widened to an `int`, and the result is an `int`.

As such, you would have to cast the `int` back to a `char`:

```
char a = (char) (c + 10);
```

However, even when adding a `char` to another `char`, both are widened to `int`, and the result is again an `int`, and so cannot be assigned to a `char` variable. The rules are basically:

- If either operand is a double, widen both to double
- Else, if either operand is a float, widen both to float
- Else, if either operand is a long, widen both to long
- Else, widen both to int

So, even if you were adding a `byte` to a `byte`, both are widened to `int`, added, and the result is an `int`.

---

The exception to this is if you made `c` `final`:

```
final char c = 34;
```

In that case, `c` has a compile-time constant value, so `c + 10` is a compile-time constant expression. Because it's a compile-time constant expression, the compiler knows its value, and knows that it fits into the range of `char`; so it would be allowed:

```
final char c = 34;
char a = c + 10;
```

Comment: Why is it that you are allowed to assign an `int` to a `char` such as `char a = 10`, but you are unable to assign the `int` result of `operator+` to a `char`?

Comment: @h0r53 `10` is a compile-time constant expression, whose value can be determined by the compiler to fit in the range of `char`. I have demonstrated that you can assign the result of addition to a `char`, provided it has a compile-time constant value.

Comment: This is misleading. It says that `c`, and the result, is widened to `int` because one of the operands is `10`, and suggests that coding `char a = c + c;` would work... but it doesn't. OP encounters the error because *all* types are widened to at least `int` when performing arithmetic.

Comment: " and suggests that coding char a = c + c; would work." where do I suggest that?

Comment: I would like to add the JLS link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2, but you keep editing :)

Comment: @Andy "the compiler knows its value, and knows that it fits into the range of char" the compiler knows that the value of `34 + 100000` is `100034`, which doesn't fit into the range of char, so it doesn't allow it.

Comment: You state that `c` is widened to `int` because `10` is an `int`, which is a false statement. `c` is widened to `int` because **all** arithmetic is done using `int`. If you added a `byte` to a `char`, the `byte` would not be widened to `char`; both would be widened to `int`.

Comment: @Bohemian I absolutely do not say that. I say "Else, widen both to int".

Comment: Rather than saying *When you add a `char` to an `int`, the `char` is widened to an `int`, and the result is an `int`.* it is more correct to say *When you add a `char` to **anything**, the `char` is widened to an `int` and the result is an `int` (except for legal compile time constants, or to `long` if the other operand is `long` etc)*

Comment: @Bohemian "When you add a char to anything" except when you add a char to a long, or a char to a float, or a char to a double. In those cases, the char is widened to a long, float or double respectively. Says it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6): "If any expression is of type double, then the promoted type is double, and other expressions that are not of type double undergo widening primitive conversion to double." etc

Comment: I was simplifying. Nevertheless, the operand `10` being `int` is not the cause of `c` being widened.

Answer (score 0):

As per the JLS, `int` is the narrowest type for arithmetic. Narrower values are widened to `int`, and the result is `int`.

You would get the same error even if you coded:

```
char a = c + c; // error
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java char is a primitive data type. It is used to declare the character-type like char **char1='a';**
But you can add an **int** to a **char**, but the result is an int - you'd have to cast back to char

```
char a = 'a';
char b = (char)(a+4);
System.out.println(b);// print "e"
```